# Semantic-UI React | Why my button has no styles?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I've stacked with some strange issue. When I create a menu block with a button inside of it, I'm expecting to get a "Regular" button, but getting, kind of, Menu Item View.[image]

Instead of

[image]

```
<Menu inverted>
    <Menu.Menu>
        <Menu.Item header>
            <Image className="logo" src={logoImg} avatar />
        </Menu.Item>
    </Menu.Menu>
    <Menu.Menu position={'right'}>
        <Menu.Item>
            <Button positive>Sign up</Button>
        </Menu.Item>
    </Menu.Menu>
</Menu>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Please add code of Button component too.

Comment: It's already there. It's a component of Semantic-UI-Rect called Button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code working fine. Here is the working [codepen](https://codepen.io/elumalaiit/pen/goMQvv). Issue may be some other custom styles will override your component `Button` styles.